# Cannot set transaction read-write mode during recovery error

Tags: postgresql

I try to insert row:

```
BEGIN;
  SET TRANSACTION READ WRITE; 
INSERT INTO soft.lk(time_added, expiration_date)
    VALUES (now(), now() + INTERVAL '730 days');
COMMIT;
```

But have following error:

```
cannot set transaction read-write mode during recovery
```

What is recovery. And how can i insert row?
Postgres version: 9.0

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have connected to a read-replica server in hot standby mode - a streaming replica, or one that's using WAL archiving, it doesn't matter.

These servers are read-only. So you cannot write to them.

Connect to the master server instead.

Comment: Whether there is a way to know ip address of master server from replica-server?

Comment: There is not. There might not be an accessible master (if you're using WAL archiving) or it might not be writable (if you're doing cascading replication). So it wouldn't be very flexible anyway.

Comment: Maybe i can use some access logs? if postgres have them.

Comment: `recovery.conf` if it is a streaming replica. If it just uses wal segments you have to find where it gets them from (see `restore_command` in `recovery.conf`) and how they get there (depends on sysadmin scripting)

Comment: Can I make this server the master?